# Is it possible to separate the table based on year in mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple column which output years. But the outputs are in a single table. Is it possible to separate the table automatically based on a different year.

```
<?php
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){ ?>

    <table>
        <thead>
            <th>Year</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            <?php
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                    $year = $row['year'];
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $year; ?></td>
                </tr>

                <?php
                    } ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
<?php } ?>
```

This outputs this

```
+------+
| year |
+------+
| 2017 |
| 2017 |
| 2018 |
+------+
```

I am looking for this

```
+------+
| year |
+------+
| 2018 |
+------+ 

+------+
| year |
+------+
| 2017 |
| 2017 |
+------+
```

Comment: In your query: GROUP BY YEAR(record_date). This is in case you use datetime as type. Otherwise you can just use GROUP BY. Also, please use PDO. It's much cleaner.

Comment: if im right you need 2 tables one with the entrys from 2017 and one for 2018 and meybe more if more years?

Comment: You can use MySQL inbuilt partitioning [Partition](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/117438) .

Comment: Yes.  Yes, it is entirely possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop just needs to check internally if the "year" has changed in the results, and output the HTML table footer/header to start a new table.  Consider the following **pseudo-code** logic:

```
results = query(); // assume ordered by year
year = 0;
first_row = true;
output_HTML_table_header();
while (row = results.next()) {
    if (year != row["year"] && !first_row) {
        output_HTML_table_footer();
        output_HTML_table_header();
    }
    year = row["year"];
    first_row = false;
    output_HTML_table_row(row);
}
output_HTML_table_footer();
```

Supposing your data is this:

```
2016
2017
2017
2018
2019
```

The output operations this produces would be:

```
HTML table header
  2016 row
HTML table footer
HTML table header
  2017 row
  2017 row
HTML table footer
HTML table header
  2018 row
HTML table footer
HTML table header
  2019 row
HTML table footer
```

The "HTML table header" output is simply:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>Year</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
```

The row is:

```
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $year; ?></td>
</tr>
```

and the footer is:

```
    </tbody>
</table>
```

You just need to alternate/repeat them in the nested logic.

Answer (score 1):

If the `$result` sql is order by year you can use this.

```
<?php
$year='';
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){ 
  echo'<table><thead><th>Year</th></thead><tbody>';
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){        
    //if a new year create new table
    if($year!=$row['year']&&$year)echo'</tbody></table><table><thead><th>Year</th></thead><tbody>';
    echo'<tr><td>'.$row['year'].'</td></tr>';
    //remeber the last year
    $year=$row['year'];
  }
  echo'</tbody></table>';
}
?>
```